# Multiple inheritance from abstract classes with same parent but different child? django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have read few threads and know that for sure django can have multiple abstract classes.  But pretty much all the samples I saw are...

```
class AbsOne(models.Model):
    pass
class AbsTwo(models.Model):
    pass

class AbsThree(AbsOne, AbsTwo):
    pass
```

but what if I have something like...

```
class AbsOne(models.Model):
    pass

class AbsTwo(AbsOne):  // this actually inheritance AbsOne
    pass
class AbsThree(AbsOne):  // this inheritance AbsOne
    pass
```

What if I need to inheritance both `AbsTwo, AbsThree` but these two are also inheritance to the same parent.

```
class AbsFour(AbsTwo, AbsThree):
    pass
```

Is this doable without any conflict or extra fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django multiple model inheritance is fubar. While you can hack things together with enough determination, save yourself a lot of trouble and don't use it. (Python MI, on the other hand, works beautifully).

Answer (score 3):

> Just as with Python’s subclassing, it’s possible for a Django model to
> inherit from multiple parent models. Keep in mind that normal Python
> name resolution rules apply. The first base class that a particular
> name (e.g. Meta) appears in will be the one that is used; for example,
> this means that if multiple parents contain a Meta class, only the
> first one is going to be used, and all others will be ignored.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance

It's possible but it has some restrictions like ( overriding fields in parent class and meta classes ) and in Django ORM or the model way of classes is a bit different in architecture than regular python inheritance, read carefully what the documentation mentions and try to keep it simple.

> ... The main use-case where this is useful is for “mix-in” classes: adding
> a particular extra field or method to every class that inherits the
> mix-in. Try to keep your inheritance hierarchies as simple and
> straightforward as possible so that you won’t have to struggle to work
> out where a particular piece of information is coming from

edited: added another quote :)