# Django ORM: Implement Pre-save for a "Field" instead of a "Model"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, validation, django-models

let's say I have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    char_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    json_field = LimitedJSONField(default={})
```

where `LimitedJSONField` is a custom field for storing JSONStrings on DB.

I would like to do pre-save check on `json_field` (e.g. truncate its length if exceeding). I have read about overriding `save` method for `MyModel`, I also know I can implement a `pre-save` signal but I would like to handle it on field-level. Because let's say I use `LimitedJSONField` on 500 models. Do I have to override `save` method for each of those 500 models? I implemented a `validate` method on `LimitedJSONField` but it does not get triggered on save (it's triggered only on form validation, i.e. `full_clean` routine).

How can I implement a validator for `LimitedJSONField`, so that whatever `Model` uses it, this field gets validated with regards to one single business logic written inside `LimitedJSONField`?

Put simply, I would like to implement the logic within `field` class and I would like to have no logic written in Model class, so that the solution is scalable for new Model classes to use this field without needing to implement boilerplace logic code.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure handling this in the save method is different than handling it in a `pre_save` signal. They both give you access to the whole instance. If you wanted to actually implement the per field signal, you'd to override `save_base` to iterate over the fields and send the signal per field. And take into account the `update_fields`.

Comment: @schillingt thank you for your response. I believe overriding `save_base` is really a big deal, since I work on a quite big project and lots of models use same save method. To put simply, I would like to implement the logic within `field` class and I would like to have no logic written in Model class, so that the solution is scalable for new Model classes to use this field without needing to implement boilerplace logic code.

Comment: Another alternative would be to create a handler for all `pre_save` senders and iterate over the fields of the instance triggering a new field specific signal.

Answer (score 1):

Could you make a parent class with a single save method and use it as a mixin that is inherited by all of your other models?

Something like:

```
class SpecialJsonModel(models.model):
    json_field = LimitedJSONField(default={})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        // Specific save logic goes here

class OtherModelA(SpecialJsonModel)
    char_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class OtherModelB(SpecialJsonModel)
    char_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Then you would only have to write one overridden save method.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your effort. I also thought about writing a mixin, but I have a question: What if my model class already inherits multiple mixins? Does the `save` method on `MyModel` propagate to all superclasses and invoke all of their `save`s?

Comment: That would make it tricky. Assuming that LimitedJSONField is a custom field, would overriding the deconstruct method help you out? You could put the extra logic in there to get the results you want. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction

Comment: How do you plan to invoke SpecialJsonModel's `save` method on the solution above?

Comment: Sorry, hit submit on my above comment too soon. Multiple save methods really won't work very easily. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583766/multiple-inheritance-from-abstract-classes-with-same-parent-but-different-child

Comment: No problems! Thank you again for your time. I'll check out `deconstruct` method and see if it helps. I'll be updating soon.

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on how can I use `deconstruct`? I checked it and I couldnt see how I could use it for my use-case.