# Proper way to do Mixins for Django models

Tags: django, orm

I have the following mixins:

```
class AbandonableMixin(object):
    is_abandoned = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, verbose_name=_('Abandoned?'))


class ReadyMixin(object):
    is_ready = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, verbose_name=_('Ready?'))


class StoppableMixin(object):
    is_stopped = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, verbose_name=_('Stopped?'))
```

I would like to use these in my class like ordinary mixins:

```
class MyObject(models.Model, AbandonableMixin, StoppableMixin): 
... 

class MySecondObject(models.Model, ReadyMixin, StoppableMixin):
...
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Model, AbandonableMixin
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should swap the inheritance order, so `class MyObject(AbandonableMixin, StoppableMixin, models.Model)`, and `class MySecondObject(ReadyMixin, StoppableMixin, models.Model)`.

Comment: Are you sure however your mixins inherit from `object`, and not from `Model`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this didn't work. I tried `MyObject(AbandonableMixin, models.Model)` but the attributes were not added.

Comment: you probably want to make *abstract* models? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Answer (score 0):

@willem-van-onsem answered, but I will try to give more detailed answer (also based on [this article](https://python.plainenglish.io/creating-reusable-models-with-django-and-mixins-2126c5f11eac)), you need to inherit from Django base model and use abstract models:

```
class AbandonableMixin(models.Model):
    is_abandoned = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class StoppableMixin(models.Model):
    is_stopped = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MyObject(AbandonableMixin, StoppableMixin): 
    ...
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583766/multiple-inheritance-from-abstract-classes-with-same-parent-but-different-child